# Thicker border lines on sticking divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating my own full calendar and I have a problem with a border.
In places where divs touch, border lines are thicker because each element has own border and obviously in this places the border is rendered twice.

Depending on month, the calendar has different layout, so hardcoding isn't a good idea.

I prepared example here:

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">1 </div>
<div class="block">2 </div>
<div class="block">3 </div>
<div class="block">4 </div>
<div class="block">5 </div>
<div class="block">6 </div>
<div class="block">7 </div>
```

[View on JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w76o9kL4/12/)

And my question is:
Is there a SMART or tricky way to solve this problem? 
I may use plain JavaScript or CSS, but not jQuery.

Comment: Isn't a calendar a sort of tabular data? That would justify you to use table, when arranging the borders would be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is just add

```
margin-right: -1px;
margin-bottom: -1px;
```

to the `.block` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/w76o9kL4/20/

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
.container{
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.block {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float:left;
}
```

Wrap all your `divs` inside a container `div` and do the above mentioned styling. This way elements will not have overlapping borders.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1 </div>
  <div class="block">2 </div>
  <div class="block">3 </div>
  <div class="block">4 </div>
  <div class="block">5 </div>
  <div class="block">6 </div>
  <div class="block">7 </div>

  <div style="clear: both"> </div>
  <div class="block">8 </div>
  <div class="block">9 </div>
  <div class="block">10 </div>
  <div class="block">11 </div>
  <div class="block">12 </div>
  <div class="block">13 </div>
  <div class="block">14 </div>
  <div style="clear: both"> </div>
  <div class="block">15 </div>
  <div class="block">16 </div>
  <div class="block">17 </div>
  <div class="block">18 </div>
  <div class="block">19 </div>
  <div class="block">20 </div>
  <div class="block">21 </div>
  <div style="clear: both"> </div>
  <div class="block">22 </div>
  <div class="block">23 </div>
  <div class="block">24 </div>
  <div class="block">25 </div>
  <div class="block">26 </div>
  <div class="block">27 </div>
  <div class="block">28 </div>
  <div style="clear: both"> </div>
  <div class="block">29 </div>
  <div class="block">30 </div>
  <div class="block">31 </div>

</div>
```

Here I have reduced the height for better visibility.

Comment: This will not work if the first of the month isn't a Sunday.

Comment: @Tiedye that totally depends on the use of OP. Every solution posted here might need some modification based on situations.

Comment: In this case, the solution presented by @Tiedye is better for me.
His idea doesn't limit calendar to start on Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Remove border right for every block except the last one.

```
<div class="block">1  </div>
<div class="block">2  </div>
<div class="block">3  </div>
<div class="block">4  </div>
<div class="block">5  </div>
<div class="block">6  </div> 
<div class="block last">7 </div>

<style>
.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float:left;
}
.last {
    border-right : 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple css3 selector using `+` you can target sibling elements. Take a look

```
.block + .block {border-left:0px;}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.block + .block {border-left:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="block">1 </div>
<div class="block">2 </div>
<div class="block">3 </div>
<div class="block">4 </div>
<div class="block">5 </div>
<div class="block">6 </div>
<div class="block">7 </div>
```